# PDFbox Using fallback font Helvetica for ZapfDingbats

Tags: pdfbox, alpine-linux

The error that I am getting is

```
2021-05-03 15:00:58.542  WARN 1 --- [nio-8099-exec-1] o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font : Using fallback font Helvetica for ZapfDingbats
2021-05-03 15:00:58.542  WARN 1 --- [nio-8099-exec-1] o.apache.pdfbox.rendering.Type1Glyph2D : No glyph for code 52 (a20) in font ZapfDingbats
```

Had similar issue with Helvetica, but after reading a response here [Pdf to image conversion using PdfBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53294940/pdf-to-image-conversion-using-pdfbox)
I added two missing fonts to /usr/local/fonts

(PDFbox is running on Docker and I am using openjdk:16-jdk-alpine3.12)

Helvetica issue was resolved, but issue with ZapfDingbats still continues.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to install the ZapfDingbats font? Or Dingbats or MS-Gothic? What PDFBox version are you using?

Comment: Yes, I have tried installing ZapfDingbats and MS-Gothic. I have not tried Dingbats. I am using 2.0.23. 
What Dingbats exact font should I try?

Comment: It should have the specific postscript names mentioned, that is what counts. Please look into the file `.pdfbox.cache` in your user directory whether the files are there. You can also delete it, it will be regenerated. (should happen automatically if there are new fonts, after a restart of the application)

Comment: Thanks for pointing into .pdfbox.cache. I managed to see what fonts were missing.
It seems that in my particular case, when I would create docker container I had to download msttcorefonts-installer and ghostscript-fonts.

For those who will get stuck on similar issue just run: 

apk --update add fontconfig msttcorefonts-installer ghostscript-fonts  && \
    fc-cache -f -v

oh, and if you are running linux, most probably that .pdfbox.cache will be under /root and that file by default is hidden so don't forget to list all (ls -a)

Comment: If this fixed your problem, please answer this yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case, the issue was that Alpine Linux (inside the container) didn't have fonts that I required (Helvetica and ZapfDingbats).

Inside my docker file I had to add

```
RUN apk --update add fontconfig msttcorefonts-installer ghostscript-fonts  && \
update-ms-fonts && \
fc-cache -f -v
```

Msttcorefonts would solve my issue with Helvetica font and no glyph error and
ghostscript-fonts would install Zapfdingbats.

Comment: This solution really works. Here is the Git repository where I practiced this solution:  https://github.com/chigix/pdfbox/commit/5f0434016eec250faeefce63726c3f3716b47f27#diff-dd2c0eb6ea5cfc6c4bd4eac30934e2d5746747af48fef6da689e85b752f39557R7